# Short exact sequence for the linear sum of $n$ submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, direct-sum

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $M$ be an $R$-module. Let $M_1,\dots, M_n$ be submodules of $M$. Is there a short exact sequence of the form

$$0\to \bigcap_{i=1}^nM_i\xrightarrow{u}\bigoplus_{i=1}^nM_i\xrightarrow{v}\sum_{i=1}^nM_i\to0~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$

where if $f_{j}$ is the obvious composition of inclusions $\bigcap_{i=1}^nM_i\to M_j\to \bigoplus_{i=1}^nM_i$ for every $j=1, \dots, n$, then $u=\sum_{j=1}^nf_j$.

I am not sure how to construct the map $v$ so that short exact sequence $(1)$ exists? In the case $n=2$, then the map is defined in *Bourbaki*'s book Algebra $I$ as $v=i-j$ where $i: M_1\to M_1+M_2$ and $j:M_2\to M_1+M_2$. How do we generalise this to an arbitrary $n$ if possible at all?

Comment: The "natural" exact sequence in this scenario is not a short exact sequence if $n>2$, see e.g. [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/26735).

Answer (score 1):

What one would expect to have is a *long* exact sequence with $j$th term given by $C_j = \bigoplus_{A\subseteq [n], |A| = j} M_A$ where $M_A=\bigcap_{a\in A} M_a$ and the differential is given by sending an element in $M_A$ to a signed sum in $M_{A\smallsetminus a}$ for $a\in A$.

But this is *not* exact in general. The key word you want is *distributivity*, see for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427510/distributive-lattice-of-subspaces). See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63493/non-distributivity-of-subspaces). In particular, try to check by hand that exactness is non-trivial already when $n=3$, i.e. there is a complex

$$0 \longrightarrow V_1\cap V_2 \cap V_3 \longrightarrow \bigoplus_{1\leqslant i<j\leqslant 3} V_i \cap V_j
   \longrightarrow \bigoplus_{1\leqslant i\leqslant 3} V_i \longrightarrow \sum_{1\leqslant i\leqslant 3} V_i \longrightarrow 0$$

which is not exact in general.